# Нет недавних изменений или повышений репутации?

Tags: дефект, репутация, профиль-участника

Если открыть чужой профиль, к примеру, [Эльдар Юсупжанов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/301852/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80-%D0%AE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2?tab=topactivity):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если свой:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём соль? В этой вкладке отображаются именно изменения. Почему иногда там фигурирует именно "повышения"?

Comment: Скорее всего кривой перевод. Ссылки то на одну страницу ведут.

Comment: @AntonSorokin нет, перевод верный. Там в оригинале такая же проблема https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323727/260198

Comment: @Suvitruf, Это все потому что ты минусы не можешь смотреть :-) у чужих

Comment: @Grundy в чужом профиле? Могу. У вас https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=3 я вижу -20.

Comment: @Suvitruf, но не все. Эм... а где там -20?

Comment: @Grundy не все. Но факт в том, что какие-то могу, значит формулировка неверная )

Comment: Да, формулировка неверная, но похоже мы не можем увидеть минусы, поставленные ему. Только от удаления участников и т.п.

Comment: @AntonSorokin мы видим summary по минусам, без подробностей.